# Long clout nails though rigid insulation boards

Tags: insulation, roof

We are building a cabin with a solid wooden roof (18mm) on which shingles are nailed. An advised method of insulation is to put rigid insulation board on top, then nail the shingles using long clout nails, say 60mm nails with 50mm of insulation.

I've discovered you can buy clout nails as long as 150mm and am wondering if this would work with much thicker insulation, rather than having to build a wooden frame so the insulation boards are 'sandwiched' between two layers of wood?

Our contractor told us 50mm insulation was the limit but I think he didn't realise you can get such long nails. Is it viable to nail shingles through 100+mm of rigid insulation?

Comment: Normally you'd install insulation, _then_ sheathing (with the long nails, then the shingles. Ideally your shingles are secured with the shortest possible nails that adequately protrude through the sheathing. What's the question?

Comment: The roof my son has done has 30cm of insulation for roof, walls and floor... reduces the heating need. All you need to do is design appropriately.

Comment: @isherwood I've clarified the Q a bit. I don't know what you mean exactly by sheathing though, might be we call it something else in the UK... perhaps you could answer with a diagram?

Comment: @SolarMike that's kind of the question... although 30cm, wow!

Comment: Sheathing is whatever lays over your rafters--usually OSB or plywood in the modern world.

Comment: Ok so in log cabins they advocate the opposite for condensation reasons. In the UK at least it's called a warm roof rather than a cold roof. But in the UK we don't typically use sheathing at all!